# Teamviewer WOL does not work

Tags: ipv6, wake-on-lan, teamviewer

I try to wake my PC from my mobile with the [Teamviewer for Remote Control app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile&hl=en). And it doesn't work.
I set up the WOL regarding the [Teamviewer WOL manual](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/Teamviewer9-Manual-Wake-on-LAN-en.pdf):

1. The Network Adapter is configured to wake on a magic packet and WOL
   works when triggered from the Fritzbox UI.
2. Teamviewer WOL option is configured.

[image]

3. Windows Firewall is disabled and Fritzbox IPv6-Portforwarding is configured.

[image]

To me it seems all configured and fine. But still, when I select the device in my teamviewer app and push the wake-button, the pc does not wake.

However I wonder how the PC should wake: AFAIK WOL-Packets can't come from outside your LAN, because it is an Ethernet packet. But how can an IP-Packet wake the PC, when only a magic packet is allowed to?

Answer (score 0):

WOL has to be supported by the network equipment and will only broadcast on layer 2, if you are not in the same network you would need to send that request from another local computer or the router to wake up the computer in question.
The router or computer would need to be able to see the WOL client computer via MAC addresses, if it cannot see it or talk to it due to VLANs or firewall settings it will not work either.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But how do I accomplish this? I do not understand how the instructions from the teamviewer-WOL-manual are supposed to work. They say to put in the ip of the computer to wake and to forward udp packets from the router... How can udp trigger WOL and why don't they say anything about it in the manual?

Comment: Do you have a switch that supports Layer2, they are usually managed. Without this, or a router that supports Layer2, you will not be able to get it to work.

Comment: I don't know, what exactly you mean by "supports layer 2". The FritzBox-router always gives the same ip to the device to wake up. You can even wake it up from the fritzbox. And I checked the option "Start this computer automatically as soon as it is accessed from the Internet". How are the instructions from the teamviewer wol manual supposed to work? Where is my mistake?

Comment: I checked the mentioned option for the device to wake in the fritzbox (router) UI.

Comment: Sorry I was out on a job over the past week.
Using any method, are you able to get this machine to boot on your network?

Comment: got it working using ipv4, but not for ipv6.

Comment: The tool is able to use IPv6? I am not sure that you are using ipv4 either, I think your router is translating. All the info I have uses MAC addressing for remote wake on lan via routers/servers.